# Angular proxy config json same entry as route

Tags: angular

I have an entry in my proxy config json, meaning - I have an API base path, that matches one of my application's routes.

I need to route to https://localhost:3000/my-api-route

But what happens is that the proxy.json catches the request and serve it to the server as an API call.

The proxy.json:

```
"/my-api-route":{
  "target":"https://my.domain.com",
  "secure":true,
  "logLevel":"debug",
  "changeOrigin":true
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer...
You can declare the proxy as a JSON or JS file.
If you use a JS file, you can add a bypass function in which you can skip requests with 'html' string contained in their header.

For example:

```
bypass: function (req, res, proxyOptions) {
  if (req?.headers?.accept?.indexOf("html") !== -1) {
    console.log("Skipping proxy for browser request.");
    return "/index.html";
  }
}
```

You can read more about it, here:
https://angular.io/guide/build#bypass-the-proxy

Answer (score 0):

You should not have both the same. Because `proxy.conf.json` file instructs Angular to proxy the request.

Comment: What do you mean by "should not have both the same" -
I have a route in my application that goes to my-api-route (for example...)
and I also have an API that this is its path <domain>/my-api-route

The question is how can I avoid making the proxy file catch my routing request and serve them as API requests to the server?

Comment: That's what I am saying. When you use `<domain>/my-api-route`, angular makes or forwards it to `my-api-route`. That's the whole point of using proxy. In general people reserve `/api/` for API calls only. But if you do what you do, you will always end up with conflict at some point of time.